# II tried to set a value using a different method, but I got compiler errors

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public class Point3D {    
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        int x=setX(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    int x=1;
    public int setX(int x) { 
        this.x=x;
    }   
}
```

The compiler(cmd) showed the following errors:

```
Point3D.java:5: error: non-static method setX(int) cannot be referenced from 
static context int x=setX(x);
  ^
1 error
```

Can anyone please help me fix this?

Comment: What's the compiler message?

Comment: Please provide a title to your question. Current title is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**

```
 public int setX(int x) { 
        this.x=x;
    }
```

That method needs to return an int value. You are not returning anything.

```
   public int setX(int x) { 
            this.x=x;
            return this.x;
        }
```

My recommendation:

It's quite confusing to return an value from setter, provide getter and get the x value from there.

**2)**

Since the method setX is not a static method you cannot access it in static context. So either you need to make that method as static or you must create a instance of the class to access that method.

```
public class Point3D {  
    int x=1;  
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
      Point3D  p = new Point3D(); 
        p.setX(1);
        int x=p.getX();
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void setX(int x) { 
        this.x=x;
    }

     public int getX() { 
        return this.x;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `setX()` must be called on an instance. Use `new Point3D()` to create an instance of your class.

Second, a non-void method must return a value. `setX()` is declared as returning an `int` but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Generate Getters And Setters Like Follows:

```
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```